# Retrieving an array of link titles matching class

Tags: jquery

How would I go about creating an array containing each link title from the following? (Link 1, Link 2, Link 3) - I'm trying to pass this data through a load() command so it then pre-caches the results to reduce load time if the user decides to click on one of the links.. (each link calls to an api fetching data related to the title)

```
<ul id="links">
    <li><a href="#" title="Link 1">Link 1</li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Link 2">Link 2</li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Link 3">Link 2</li>
</ul>
```

My idea:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("#links li a"); 
var arr = jQuery.makeArray(elems);
??
```

But i'm not sure how to get just the title attr() of each link and send it over as an array

Thank you
:D

**Perhaps it's better to use each() and then have the load() within that, so it makes independent load calls recursively?**

Something like this instead:

```
    $("#similar-artists li a").each(function() { 
                    alert("alert");  // load();
});
```

Comment: I see you've accepted an alternative answer below, but please consider using the built-in methods do to these sort of operations, if you're including a library you might as well take advantage of it...it's also more efficient in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to get the array of titles, for example:

```
var arr = $("#links a").map(function() { return this.title; }).get();
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Bn4Ek/).

Comment: @zolex - I think it's lack of understanding really, it was posted first as well, but that's beside the point...I want to stress doing things it a much more efficient way when possible, this eliminates a loop and a lot of unnecessary logic to get a basic DOM property.

Comment: haha there are teh same loops in map()'s intermals.. but anyway (+1) ;)

Comment: @zolex - One loop, not two :), and `.attr("tittle")` is *way* more expensive than `.title` :)

Comment: well, where do you see two loops?

Comment: @zolex - `.attr()` internally you're creating an object, and to fetch based on the jQuery object itself after that...I'm not really sure how you'd argue going though `.attr()` vs `.title` would *ever* be faster really?

Answer (score 2):

a quite simple task :)

```
var myArray = new Array();
$('#links li a').each(function() {

  myArray.push($(this).attr('title'));
});
```

Comment: Why do it the long way with `.map()` is specifically for this purpose, and much more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

How about just iterating over the elements and building an array of titles, like this:

```
var elems = $("#links li a");
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++)
  arr.push(elems[i].title);
```