# Jquery: make array of all pager items

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

127.0.0.1/test?page=1, 127.0.0.1/test?page=2, 127.0.0.1/test?page=3.

How do I make a array of all the new items on the pager.

I want to only save the elements within that page
that has the class `item-new` to the array.

To be more clear: I want a element with all of the html code inside written to the array.

<-- previous **1** of **5** next -->

This is the method for getting the pages:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1/index?page=1
```

Pager HTML code:

```
<div class="item-list">
<ul class="pager">
<li class="pager-current">1</li>
<li class="pager-item">
<a class="active" title="Go to page 2" href="/challenges?page=1">2</a>
</li>
<li class="pager-next">
<a class="active" title="Go to next page" href="/challenges?page=1">next ›</a>
</li>
<li class="pager-last">
</ul>
</div>
```

I appreciate all these great supporters! :}

Comment: so you want to get all the url's in a array from the pager? If so, we must now how the pager is built. Have some html for us?

Comment: Are all the pages included in the same page (page 1 and page 2 being in hidden elements all on the same page), or are they entirely different pages? If they're all different pages, then this needs to be addressed by your server-side script.

Comment: no just the items within the pager urls. the pager is just a simple a href to the new page. Im posting the html.

Comment: Im currently using ajax on the site and when I scroll down ajax gets the items via `GET http://127.0.0.1/index?page=1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we assume that all the `a` elements inside the pager will contain URLs to the pages, we can do something like this:

```
var pages = [];
$('ul.pager a').each(function({
    pages.push( $(this).attr('href') );
}));
```

This will populate the `pages` array with all the links.

Comment: Will that save all the NEW items on that page?

Comment: What do you mean by the new items? If you add more `a` elements with ajax, you would have to wrap the code I wrote in a function and run it every time the AJAX call is made.

Comment: for example: page1 has item,item,item. page2 has item, item, item. Within each page there is multiple classes called item. I only want those items to be added to the array.

Comment: I think using jquery's map and get is a better approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791876/retrieving-an-array-of-link-titles-matching-class